# Good way to update numerous packages with minimal MySQL downtime

Tags: apt, upgrade, mysql

If I run the following command:

```
apt list --upgradable
```

then there are numerous packages which need to be upgraded:

```
Listing... Done
grub-common/bionic-updates 2.02-2ubuntu8.23 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21]
grub-pc/bionic-updates 2.02-2ubuntu8.23 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21]
grub-pc-bin/bionic-updates 2.02-2ubuntu8.23 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21]
grub2-common/bionic-updates 2.02-2ubuntu8.23 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.02-2ubuntu8.21]
initramfs-tools/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 0.130ubuntu3.12 all [upgradable from: 0.130ubuntu3.11]
initramfs-tools-bin/bionic-updates 0.130ubuntu3.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.130ubuntu3.11]
initramfs-tools-core/bionic-updates,bionic-updates 0.130ubuntu3.12 all [upgradable from: 0.130ubuntu3.11]
intel-microcode/bionic-updates,bionic-security 3.20210216.0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2]
libmysqlclient20/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
libnss-systemd/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
libpam-systemd/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
libsystemd0/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
libudev1/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
linux-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.143.130 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.142.129]
linux-headers-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.143.130 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.142.129]
linux-image-generic/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.143.130 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.142.129]
linux-libc-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-143.147 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0-142.146]
mysql-client-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
mysql-client-core-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
mysql-server/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
mysql-server-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
mysql-server-core-5.7/bionic-updates,bionic-security 5.7.34-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
systemd/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
systemd-sysv/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
ubuntu-advantage-tools/bionic-updates 27.0.2~18.04.1 all [upgradable from: 17]
udev/bionic-updates 237-3ubuntu10.47 amd64 [upgradable from: 237-3ubuntu10.46]
```

Previously, when we upgraded all packages using `apt upgrade`, we noticed that MySQL would go down, and we needed to wait until all packages were upgraded before MySQL would reboot. This would take several minutes, and all websites on this server would go down while waiting for MySQL to reboot.

Therefore, how can we minimize MySQL downtime while upgrading all of the packages on the server?

For example, I am contemplating upgrading only MySQL packages with the following commands:

```
apt --only-upgrade install mysql-client-5.7
apt --only-upgrade install mysql-client-core-5.7
apt --only-upgrade install mysql-server
apt --only-upgrade install mysql-server-5.7
apt --only-upgrade install mysql-server-core-5.7
```

and then, once MySQL packages have been upgraded, upgrade all other packages with a simple `apt upgrade` command.

Is this a good approach to minimizing MySQL downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what I do with production servers that are dedicated for a database engine is `hold` a package, preventing them from being updated until I’ve had enough time to test the update in the development and/or staging environments.

You can do this with `apt` like so:

```
sudo apt-mark hold {package}
```

This makes it possible to install all the other updates for a system without potentially breaking something in the database. When you’re ready to update MySQL, you can remove the hold like this:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold {package}
```

What’s nice about this method is that updates and security patches can be applied to the server weekly while the database updates are performed only during scheduled maintenance windows every quarter. (Unless something really important needs to be pushed out, of course).

Comment: This is awesome/wonderful, thank you so much for your response.